# iOS : detect the movie aspect ratio

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am developing a DRM video player using AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem that can play either streamed or plain file movies.

I want to know if it is possible to detect the aspect ratio of the movie so that I can do some pan in / pan out to play the movie with or without the eventual black stripes.

I had a look at CoreMedia Framework, but the is not any real good documentation as most of the methods are not explained.

Do any of you guys have any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was pretty simple actually : just have to use the videoGravity of the AVPLayer and it all worked out.